# iPhone Dev - UIToolbar goes in window or view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitoolbar, uiwindow

Should I put the UIToolbar right in the window at the bottom, and then put the view above it (so the view doesn't continue underneath the toolbar), or should I just make the view cover the whole window and then add the toolbar as a subview to the view? So my question is, should the toolbar be a subview of the view or the window?
 - the window: the toolbar would be on the same level as the view, and would not overlap it
- the view: it would be inside the view.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to add the toolbar as a subview to the view. Views optimize themselves to not draw any part that is covered up by a subview, so you shouldn't get a performance hit by doing this either.